# Prove the following is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can any one solve the following:

Denote by $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ the set of all polynomials with integer coefficients, and set $$\mathbb{Z}(X):=\left\{\frac{p(X)}{q(X)}: p(X),q(X)\in\mathbb{Z}[X],\ q(X)\neq 0\right\}.$$ Show that $\mathbb{Z}(X)$ is a field by verifying that it satisfies the six field properties.

My thanks, and I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Where you get stuck?

Comment: What do you mean by the notation $\: p(X)/q(X)\:?$ Is it a formal expression? Or does it denote an element of some larger known field?

Comment: $p(X)/q(X)$ are polynomials with integer coefficients

Comment: Now write down each of the six field properties and verify them.  You need to find an additive identity and a multiplicative identity-do you have any thoughts what they might be?

Comment: $p$ and $q$ are polynomials, but what does the notation $p/q$ mean to you?

Comment: What are the six field properties? How do you go about verifying that your set satisfies them?

Comment: well, I can go through the six field properties if I have a set of numbers, but I really don't know how to go about with a field of objects

Comment: Hint: mimic the [formal construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number#Formal_construction) of rational numbers as equivalence classes of pairs of integers.

Answer (score 1):

Hint! Sum of two rational polynomials is a rational polynomial, so is the product. $0$ and $1$ are rational polynomials. Since $q(x) \neq 0$, $\frac {p(x)} {q(x)}$ $\frac {q(x)} {p(x)} =1$, What else do you need for a field? Since commutativity and associativity are obvious !

Comment: The answer is mathematically meaningless without any rigorous definition of these so-called "rational polynomials" $\, p(x)/q(x).\ $

Comment: i think the OP described it in his question, the question is about showing it a field

Comment: A [field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) is a set F with certain operations on F satisfying certain axioms. I see none of the above in your answer. It is not even clear what you intend to use as the underlying set of your field. See my hint in a comment to the question for one rigorous method to construct the desired field.